# Compiling OpenCV 3.4.1 for both Nvidia Jetson TX1 and TX2

Tags: opencv3.0, nvidia-jetson

I'm attempting to compile (and package) OpenCV 3.4.1 on a Jetson TX2 so that it will run on both a TX1 (architecture #53) and TX2 (architecture #62).  I'm building on a TX2 running Ubuntu 16.04.   Try as I might, I can only get it to compile for the TX2.

I've tried:

> export CUDA_ARCH_BIN="53, 62"

and

> export CUDA_ARCH_BIN="53 62"

before doing the cmake command, but the configuration only gives:

> NVIDIA GPU arch:             62

I'm sure there is a variable that can be set for this, but I have not been able to find it.